# Why dont the chocolatey install instructions work?

Tags: windows-7, installation, powershell, package-management, chocolatey

So I am trying really hard to follow the instructions given for chocolatey install, but they don't work.

From their [site](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation), they say "Its so easy to install!", and to "just open a power shell" and just run this command:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex
((new-object
net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
&& SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

However I get:
[image]

Comment: The instructions say to paste that command in a COMMAND PROMPT not a Powershell window.

Comment: As @DavidMarshall points out, you're running that from within PowerShell (hence the "PS" before you C: prompt), run it from a bare, non-PS command-line.

Comment: @DavidMarshall I think that did it - I was not aware that there would/should be a difference. I tried that originally in GitBash but it didnt work. I just opened a vanilla cmd prompt and (I think) it worked. Why is there a difference? But thanks I think it has worked...

Comment: @techie007 Thanks that did it! So I take it that chocolatey can ONLY be run on cmd prompt, and nothing else? (Like GitBash, etc?) Why/How should it make a difference? Thanks again!!

Comment: The command you used starts Powershell from a command prompt, sets up the correct Powershell environment, then downloads and installs chocolatey. The command lower down can be entered straight into Powershell to download and install chocolatey but you would have to ensure that the correct execution policy was set up beforehand.

Comment: `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` have completely different parsers. `@command` syntax works only in cmd.exe, and makes sense only in scripts (.cmd/ .bat) - it would run command without showing it on the screen. That's why this command failed entirely in `powershell.exe`.

Comment: @BartekB thanks Bartek! And I imagine a similar thing for GitBash as well?

Comment: My bash knowledge is a bit rusty, but as far as I know - `@command` syntax is unique to `cmd.exe` - haven't seen it in any other shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already seen from the comments, you need a **command prompt** as stated on the Chocolatey web site:

> To install chocolatey now, open a command prompt and paste the text from the box below and press enter

Command (or strictly `cmd` on newer Windows versions), PowerShell and Bash all have very different syntax though they serve similar aims in many ways.

Chocolatey *does* use PowerShell but, as others have said in the comments, the initial kick-off is from a simple command prompt. The power of PowerShell is then used by Chocolatey to automate software installs and updates. It is a neat and powerful tool though as with many installer tools, it can serve up out-of-date software all too regularly.

I make extensive use of it though, especially recently when I've had to rebuild a load of development laptops quickly. Great way to install a load of standard software quickly and consistently & keep it reasonably up-to-date.

Comment: Thank you kind Sir! May you please expand on what you said about the differences between cmd/PS/Bash? I THOUGHT they were all the same, as in, did the same thing... if they have slightly different syntax, then why have all of them? I guess I am not getting why we have so many different types of 'command line' programs like those? Thanks.

Comment: At the danger of being told off for misusing comments! The original command prompt stems from DOS days, got improved for Windows NT (cmd) but is still pretty pants! BASH and similar stem from UNIX and are very powerful command environments with quite a few power tools and features built in. PowerShell is MS's answer to BASH. Officially it exposes MS's .NET environment (libraries) into a command environment. If you want to become a Windows GURU, PowerShell is pretty essential these days and for good reason - massively powerful.

Comment: PowerShell - for example, I've just written some stats functions in PS for analysing the emails going in and out of Outlook. I also use it to help manage Office 365 & SharePoint. So each environment either has specific enhancements or is generally an evolution from older technologies, kept around for backwards compatibility. BASH on Windows is of limited use generally though I've used it to run some Photo metadata scripts and it is used to allow tools such as GIT to be cross-platform though they were developed for UNIX.

Comment: Ah, I see. And that is why gitBASH has similar linux-y commands, since it spawned from BASH, (from Linux)... interesting! :-)

Comment: Exactly. Look up CYGWIN for a more fully featured POSIX (UNIXy) environment for Windows.